# Android Virtual Device do not respond

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, mobile-devices

I´m new in the Android applications development world and I wanted to make a little test on the emulator.

Here is the problem,  I create a new Android Virtual Device with this settings:

[image]

Then, I press "Start", and then Launch. Which takes me to this waiting black background android window:

[image]

And after waiting a quite long time, it turns into this new window that, after waiting the minute, says "Couldnt Connect to the Internet, swipe for more options"

[image]

So, can anyone know whats wrong with this ? What am I missing ?

Thanks.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer to your question, but i can suggest an alternative that really untied my hands. Download and use Genymotion emulator instead of AVD. Its way more simple to configure and much more faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by the device not finding an internet connection. If you have a LAN card installed, it is trying to pull DNS from the LAN card, which generally isn't an issue if you are plugged directly into the internet. Since most people run on wireless these days, I assume you are as well.

Try disabling your LAN card and rerunning to see if that will fix your issue.